# Puppet: Adding multiple AD users to local group

Tags: puppet

I am trying to add multiple AD users on a Windows Server 2012 to the `Administrators` group, but it's throwing an error. If I specify only a single user in the `params.pp` file, then it works fine.

**params.pp**

```puppet
$user_to_add = [
    'ad8\iisuser',
    'ad8\dbuser',
],
$group_name = 'Administrators',
```

**add_user_to_local_group.pp**

```puppet
class common::add_user_to_local_group (
    $user_to_add = $common::params::user_to_add,
    $group_name  = $common::params::group_name,
) inherits common::params {
    $user_to_add.each |$user_name| {
        group { "Add $user_name to local group":
            ensure  => present,
            name    => $group_name,
            members => [ $user_name ],
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

```
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 500 on SERVER: {"message":"Server Error: Evaluation Error: Error while eval
uating a Resource Statement, Cannot alias Group[Add ad8\\dbuser to local group] to [\"Administrators\"] at /etc/puppetlabs/code/en
vironments/automation/modules/common/manifests/add_user_to_local_group.pp:6; resource [\"Group\", \"Administrators\"] already declared
at /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/automation/modules/common/manifests/add_user_to_local_group.pp:6 at /etc/puppetlabs/code/environme
nts/automation/modules/common/manifests/add_user_to_local_group.pp:6:9 on node lab.ad8.com","issue_kind":"RUNTIME_ERROR","stacktrace
":["Warning: The 'stacktrace' property is deprecated and will be removed in a future version of Puppet. For security reasons, stacktrac
es are not returned with Puppet HTTP Error responses."]}
```

Comment: looks quite alright. are you sure you're not mistakenly declaring a user earlier in your manifests?

Comment: I checked again but my node block only has the following: `include common::add_user_to_local_group`. Also, the manifest i pasted above is the complete manifest. I also checked for variable `$user_to_add` but it's not declared anywhere else. Tried adding both users manually and it works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to circumvent resource uniqueness/multiple declarations by providing a different title for the two resources, but resources must also have unique namevars https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/4.9/lang_resources.html#namenamevar. The namevar for the `group` resource is `name`, which is aliased from the title if not specified in the attributes (hence the error message output being what it is) https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/type.html#group-attribute-name.

Thus, when you declare two resources for

```
group { "Add $user_name to local group":
  ensure  => present,
  name    => $group_name,
  members => [ $user_name ],
}
```

with the same `name` attribute like you are doing when you iterate over the hash (since `$group_name` is the same for both), then you will have a multiple declaration error thrown. This is also why it works for you when you specify only a single user, since you then have `namevar` uniqueness.

To fix this, you need to have only one `group` resource that adds both users simultaneously instead of sequentially.

```
class common::add_user_to_local_group (
  $user_to_add = $common::params::user_to_add,
  $group_name  = $common::params::group_name,
) inherits common::params {
  group { $group_name:
    ensure  => present,
    members => $user_to_add,
  }
}
```

I would also recommend pluralizing the use of the word 'user' for clarification (`$user_to_add` --> `$users_to_add`). Another improvement may be to allow passing in multiple groups and iterating over those with an associated member hash, but you can decide that for yourself.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. :) I know about `namevar` but it was really stupid of me not to comprehend it properly in this case. I also feel that though this error mentions duplicate declaration, it isn't really very clear. May be it's just me. Anyways. I was smiling when reading about changing the word 'user' to 'users' because i was going to do that but after resolving this issue. That definitely is the right thing to do to provide clarity. And thanks for the multiple group thing. I was thinking of that too but in a different (not a good one) way. Your suggestion makes much sense. :)